# Django many to one relationship

Tags: python, django, one-to-many

Suppose I have a model like this :

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = RichTextField()
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.title


class Comments(models.Model):
      post_id = models.ForeignKey(Post)
      author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      content = models.TextField()
      publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content
```

Now for example i have many comments for a blog post id 1, then how would retrieve all the comments in that particular post ?

Comment: Where is the mnodel `Post`?? By `Blog` you meant `Post`?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should rename your `Comments` model to `Comment`, as it represent a single comment. Then you would do this:

```
post = Post.objects.get(pk=1)
comments = post.comment_set.all()
```

You can [read more about reverse relationships in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

**Edit:** Yes, you can also do this in a template. Provided you get a post object in a variable named `post` you could do something similar to this (obviously you would need to add some HTML):

```
{% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
    {{ comment.author }}: {{ comment.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Great. You should also probably rename `post_id` to `post`. The field represents your _relation_ to the particular post, not just its id. When creating database schema Django automatically appends "_id" to `ForeignKey` field names to create a column name... so right now in your database this column is named "post_id_id", which doesn't make much sense ;)

Comment: Okay,and also i would like to know how would i do this in the template

Comment: like i want to run a loop for it ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you rephrase?

Comment: I would like to show the comments list on particular blog post page, how would I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a relation like that, you can access related objects through the objects managers generated by Django.

For accessing all the comments from a post you can:

```
comments = one_post.comment_set.all()
```

you can change the manager´s name (comment_set) by specifying the `related_name` option in the `ForeignKey` field

```
post_id = Foreignkey(Post, related_name=comments)
```

and the you can:

```
comments = one_post.comments.all()
```

See: [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) reference of Django documentation.

**Answering to you last question:**

You could write a template for listing the comments like this:

```
<ol>
    {% for comment in comments %}
    <li>{{ comment }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Where `comments` is a variable passed to template from the view. In others words, it's the value you obtain with `comments = one_post.comment_set.all()`

Comment: Could you tell me how would i do it in the template ?